# Laravel 8 custom smtp details per Notification Job

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am currently developing a Laravel application where different users can sign up to send emails to users.

Example:
Company A has an account and stores SMTP details in the database.
Company B also has an account and stores SMTP details in the database.

Each company has its own set of customer data (especially emails)

To send emails I use the notification environment of Laravel.

If company A now wants to send a notification to all customers, I don't want to use the SMTP details of the .env file. And company B should also send with their own data.

Here is an overview of the files in the "workflow":

AnnouncementController.php:

```
(...)

    dispatch(new SendNewAnnouncementNotificationJob($announcement));

(...)
```

SendNewAnnouncementNotificationJob.php

```
(..)

     Notification::route('mail', $subscriber->email)
    ->notify((new NewAnnouncement($announcement)));

(..)
```

NewAnnouncement.php

```
   (...)
     
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
    (...)
    
    class NewAnnouncement extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
    {
    
    (...)

 use Queueable;

(...)
    public function toMail($notifiable)
        {
    
            return (new MailMessage)
                 ->from($this->announcement['sender_name'])
                ->subject('New Announcement at '.$this-> announcement['pagename'].'')
                        ->line($announcement['text'])
                        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
        }

(..)
```

At which point could I now store individual SMTP details, especially considering the queue function?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define two further mailers within `config/mail.php`.

These can the be switched by their name; eg. `Mail::mailer('smtp-company01')`.

The configuration is hardcoded - but the name of the mailer can be queried.